# pass multiple innerhtml to update twitter status and encode

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, encode, getelementbyid

I am trying to make a link that tweets the dynamically dreated content of a number of divs all as one sentence

The Javascript

```
function toggle(){
      var joe = document.getElementById("fulltxt");
      document.getElementById("tweet").setAttribute('href','http://twitter.com/home?status=' + 

joe.innerHTML)
  }
```

The content i want to tweet

```
<div id="fulltxt">
<div id='action'> actiontext </div>
<div id='reason'> reasontext</div>
<div id="party"> partytext </div>
</div>
```

the link to tweet

```
<a id="tweet" href='#' onClick="toggle(this.value)">שתף בטוויטר</a>
```

The problem i am getting is

`Invalid Unicode value in one or more parameters /intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=%3Cdiv+id%3D%22action%22%3E%F9%EC%E5%ED%3C%2Fdiv%3E%E5%E6%E4+%E1%E2%EC%EC%3Cdiv+id%3D%22party%22%3E%E1%E9%E1%E9+%F0%FA%F0%E9%E4%E5%3C%2Fdiv%3E`

There could be two problems

1. the html tags - so instead i would need string together the individual div's (action + reason + party) instead of using fulltxt
2. the language - (its its in hebrew) I think it may be an encoding issue

to test it, i replaced fulltxt in the function with the id of one of the individual divs and when the content of the individual div is in english it works but when its in hebrew it gives me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct it is an encoding issue. Also innerHTML will include the tags of the nested divs.
IE supports innerText and the rest use [textContent](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07)

```
function toggle(){
  var joe = document.getElementById("fulltxt");
  var text = joe.textContent?joe.textContent:joe.innerText;
  document.getElementById("tweet").setAttribute('href','http://twitter.com/home?status=' + 
  encodeURIComponent(text);
}
```

[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

> Encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI) component by replacing each
>   instance of certain characters by one,
>   two, three, or four escape sequences
>   representing the UTF-8 encoding of the
>   character (will only be four escape
>   sequences for characters composed of
>   two "surrogate" characters).

Comment: great works bit only one part now how do i string together the contents of the individual divs

Comment: innerText instead of inner html

Comment: Ah, yes, apologies. I missed that